# StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptio error occurred while using yahoo finance api in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get stock price information using yahoo finance api in Kotlin.
https://financequotes-api.com/
I wrote the code referring to the description, but I keep getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
An error occurs.
The gradle and menifest settings are attached below.

```
package com.jym.assetallocation


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val vBinding by lazy {ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)}


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(vBinding.root)
        vBinding.testBtn.setOnClickListener {

            Thread(Runnable {
                try{
                    val stock = YahooFinance.get("AAPL")
                    val price = stock.quote.price
                    Log.d("test", price.toString())
                }catch(err:Exception){
                    Log.d("test", err.toString())
                }
                this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                })
            }).start()
        }
    }

}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: '3.5.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

[image]

```
2022-10-04 14:29:16.291 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
2022-10-04 14:29:16.291 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2064)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at yahoofinance.quotes.stock.StockQuotesRequest.parseCSVLine(StockQuotesRequest.java:126)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at yahoofinance.quotes.stock.StockQuotesRequest.parseCSVLine(StockQuotesRequest.java:11)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at yahoofinance.quotes.QuotesRequest.getResult(QuotesRequest.java:95)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.getQuotes(YahooFinance.java:355)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:85)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:69)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at com.jym.assetallocation.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-2$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:25)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at com.jym.assetallocation.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$3MbZcd1DL5t6rNGYiArXMujwWms(Unknown Source:0)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at com.jym.assetallocation.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:2)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2022-10-04 14:29:16.292 29579-29605/com.jym.assetallocation D/test: kotlin.Unit
```

Comment: Can you attach the entire stack trace with that error please?

Comment: can you change the `Log.d("test", err.toString())` to `err.printStackTrace()`? then, get the stack trace and add that stack trace to this question.

Comment: sorry. I was working night shift, so I just modified the code, and the output is above.

Answer (score 0):

Since I directly download the latest version of the yahoo finance api jar file and use it, it works normally.

[image]

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jym.yftest"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val vBinding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)}
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(vBinding.root)

        vBinding.testBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Thread(Runnable {
                try{
                    val stock = YahooFinance.get("AAPL")
                    val price = stock.quote.price
                    Log.d("test", price.toString())

                    val stock2 = YahooFinance.get("VOO")
                    val price2 = stock2.quote.price
                    Log.d("test", price2.toString())

                }catch(err:Exception){
                    Log.d("test", err.toString())
                }
                this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                })
            }).start()
        }
    }

}
```

**result**

2022-10-04 23:00:40.799 2328-2377/com.jym.yftest D/test: 145.14
2022-10-04 23:00:40.952 2328-2377/com.jym.yftest D/test: 346.076